# LG - Fastboot doesn't recognize my device

Tags: rooting, adb, fastboot

I'm trying to get flash a custom recovery on my LG p760, however when I type `fastboot devices` in the command prompt (while booted into fastboot mode) nothing shows up. `adb devices` works fine though. I have installed all necessary drivers as well.

I have read that sometimes it doesn't show up but it still works to flash etc. But In my case that's not true. If I try to flash something it just says `<waiting for device>` all the time and nothing appears on my phone screen.

This is really frustrating because I have searched for a fix everywhere without success.

Comment: @maxpesa I am on windows 8.

Comment: There are usually different drivers needed for fastboot vs. "standard" drivers. I don't know what drivers LG P760 uses though.

Comment: yes, windows 8 is famous for this, I had problems too the very first time, have you tried Jerry's solution?

Answer (score 1):

As someone who literally just had to fix this issue for my LG V30, this is an issue with incorrect drivers being assigned to the fastboot device by windows. USB3 is not an issue.

What happens is the device is assigned *Android ADB Interface* driver when running normally. Then when the device switches into fastboot mode, windows does not correctly assign the *Android Bootloader Interface* driver to the fastboot device (no idea why).

Here are the steps to fix this issue, taken from [this site](https://www.thewindowsclub.com/install-download-install-fastboot-drivers-on-windows). This assumes that your device is **already being correctly recognized by adb**. If not follow the directions there to install adb drivers and get your device connecting to adb first.

1. Get the latest windows drivers [from Android Studio download
   page](https://developer.android.com/studio/run/win-usb)
   (usb_driver_r13-windows.zip at time of writing)
2. Extract the contents of the zipfile to a folder. Ex: `C:\drivers\usb_driver_r13-windows\`
3. Connect the device to your computer and use adb to reboot into fastboot: `adb reboot bootloader`
4. Verify fastboot does not detect the device by running: `fastboot devices`. If your devices is not listed, continue on, otherwise stop now.
5. Open device manager and look for your device under `Other devices`. Mine was listed as `Android`
6. Right click the device and select `Update driver`
7. Select `Browse my computer for drivers`
8. Select `Let me pick from a list of available drivers on my computer`
9. The next screen asks to select the device's type. Select `Show All Devices` and click next.
10. Click the `Have Disk` button.
11. Click `Browse` and select the android usb driver. `C:\drivers\usb_driver_r13-windows\usb_driver\android_winusb.inf` then press `OK`
12. When it asks you to select the device driver you want to install, select `Android Bootloader Interface` and click Next.
13. You will be prompted with a dialog box `Update Driver Warning`, this is expected as windows couldn't identify which driver to use for this device anyway. Click `Yes` to continue.
14. You should hear sounds of windows disconnecting and reconnecting the device. Verify the device is now recognized by running `fastboot devices`

I realize this is now almost 2 years after your post, but I found this as someone looking to fix the exact same issue and wanted to make sure a correct solution was available.

Answer (score 0):

I had same problem and it was because of USB3 PORT. When I changed usb cable to USB2 port fast boot drivers get installed and the error gone.

Comment: USB3 causes problems with writing data. It causes no issues in detecting the device.

Comment: @DanishShakeel what if the software not detect/support/handle the USB3 port!

Comment: Fastboot does not usually have any issues with detecting devices on a USB3. The most probable cause is 'incompatible drivers'. Go to Win+R, type devmgmt.msc, and uninstall Fastboot drivers. Now, add legacy hardware and choose Google Fastboot.